# How to group records by hours considering start date and end date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to group records by hours with consideration of duration. Assume there are long running processes and there is log data when process has been started and finished. I'm trying to get report by hours how many processes were running

The data looks like this

```
Process_name      Start                End

'A'              '2019/01/01 14:10'   '2019/01/01/ 14:55'
'B'              '2019/01/01 14:20'   '2019/01/01/ 16:30'
'C'              '2019/01/01 15:05'   '2019/01/01/ 15:10'
```

The result should be like this

```
Hour    ProcessQount
14      2
15      2
16      1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it if you join a recursive cte which returns all the hours of the day to the table:

```
with cte as (
  select 0 as hour
  union all
  select hour + 1 
  from cte 
  where hour < 23 
)
select c.hour Hour, count(*) ProcessQount 
from cte c inner join tablename t
on c.hour between datepart(hh, t.[Start]) and datepart(hh, t.[End])
group by c.hour
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=2b26b84c9c5dc1118a324e853cbd04be).
Results:

```
> Hour | ProcessQount
> ---: | -----------:
>   14 |            2
>   15 |            2
>   16 |            1
```

If you change to a `LEFT JOIN` and `count([Process_name])` then you get results for all the hours of the day:

```
> Hour | ProcessQount
.........................
>   12 |            0
>   13 |            0
>   14 |            2
>   15 |            2
>   16 |            1
>   17 |            0
>   18 |            0
.........................
```

Comment: Thanks @forpas, your solution does the trick and thanks for mentioning `LEFT JOIN` option, this is that what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Generate the hours and then use inequalities and aggregation:

```
select h, count(t.process_name)
from (values (14), (15), (16)) v(h) left join
     t
     on datepart(hour, start <= v.h) and
        datepart(hour, end >= v.h)
group by v.h
order by v.h;
```

For reasonable results, this assumes that all the data you are looking at is for one day, as in your sample data.